# Deep search in an array typescript in parent child as representation

Tags: typescript

In Typescript, I have an array that will represent a menu list, as follows.

```
export interface IMenuItem {
  label: string;
  icon: string;
  url?: string | '#';
  isActive?: boolean | false;
  items?: Array<IMenuItem>;
}

export const hrdMenu: Array<IMenuItem> = [
  {
    label: 'Dashboard',
    icon: 'speed',
    url: 'dashboard',
  },
  {
    label: 'Data Pribadi',
    icon: 'badge',
    items: [
      {
        label: 'Sub Menu 1',
        url: 'cuti-karyawan',
        icon: 'fiber_manual_record',
      },
      {
        label: 'Sub Menu 2',
        url: 'profile',
        icon: 'fiber_manual_record',
      },
      {
        label: 'Sub Menu 3',
        url: 'riwayat-absensi',
        icon: 'fiber_manual_record',
      },
    ],
  },
  {
    label: 'Settings',
    icon: 'settings',
    items: [
      {
        label: 'Agama',
        url: 'agama',
        icon: 'fiber_manual_record',
      },
      {
        label: 'Als. Berhenti Bekerja',
        url: 'alasan-berhenti-bekerja',
        icon: 'fiber_manual_record',
      },
    ],
  },
];
```

The representation of the array above is:

- Every element that has `items` element is a `parent`.
- And the element in `items` is `children`.

My Goal is, I want to access `url`: `agama`,
then `parent` will have the value `isActive : true`, as follows:

```
[
  {
    label: 'Dashboard',
    icon: 'speed',
    url: 'dashboard',
  },
  {
    label: 'Data Pribadi',
    icon: 'badge',
    items: [
      {
        label: 'Sub Menu 1',
        url: 'cuti-karyawan',
        icon: 'fiber_manual_record',
      },
      {
        label: 'Sub Menu 2',
        url: 'profile',
        icon: 'fiber_manual_record',
      },
      {
        label: 'Sub Menu 3',
        url: 'riwayat-absensi',
        icon: 'fiber_manual_record',
      },
    ],
  },
  {
    label: 'Settings',
    icon: 'settings',
    isActive : true,  ==============================> Set value                           
    items: [
      {
        label: 'Agama',
        url: 'agama',          =====================> Match here
        icon: 'fiber_manual_record',
      },
      {
        label: 'Als. Berhenti Bekerja',
        url: 'alasan-berhenti-bekerja',
        icon: 'fiber_manual_record',
      },
    ],
  },
];
```

Any suggestion it`s so appreciated.

Comment: Is every `url` value unique? What should happen if `"agama"` appears in multiple places?  Do you want to modify the existing array in-place or copy it?  Does [this approach](https://tsplay.dev/w2Q9VW) work for your needs or am I missing something?  Please [edit] to clarify.

Comment: Your approach is acceptable